# How to extract images from website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to extract images url from website using javascript, but i want that the url of the image to be extracted on which image the mouse is placed. I want the complete url

Comment: Can we see what you've tried that isn't working for you?

Comment: Actually, I have an IFrame in which I open a website link once the website link is opened suppose there are certain images from that I want the complete url of that image on which I place my mouse and then I want to save it in database since I am new to coding so I am not getting exact Idea

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Pal I have solved the problem finding a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "img", function(event){ 
  console.log($(this).attr("src")); 
});
```

This binds to all mouseover events of all img elements on that site and returs their source attribute

Here is more info on how jQuery's on() is working: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hi, thanks but I am little bit new can you please provide some sort of complete example or link to some example which is understood by me or tell me where can I place this code and how

Comment: you'll have to include jQuery from jQuery.com. then you could place that code inside a <script> tag at the end of your html body.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fazQD/, see the generated sourcecode here: view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/fazQD/show/

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy that was a good one +1 from me, I have one more query in this I have an IFrame and I am opening a website in it now what I want is the website inside the IFrame consist of several images now I want if I move the mouse over to any of the images it should display the URL of the image.

Comment: I think I am not able to explain myself clearly, If I open any website and mouseover on any image in the website then it should display the complete image url

Comment: it is not possible to execute javascript in an arbitrary iframe. that would be a severe security problem. if you want to make a tool to extract image urls from other pages, i suggest you make a bookmarklet.  that is a kind of a favorite that instead of opening a page, is executing javascript. try this generator: http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/ then you can add your bookmarklet to your browser bar and activate it on any website you want

Comment: thanks for your suggestion buddy it helped me a lot, I have solved the problem with your precious help